# How can I get citations for my self-published ebook?

Tags: citations, books

A couple of colleagues and I were thinking about publishing a book in engineering. I have heard repeatedly that people who go with a traditional publisher don't get any royalties, they transfer the copyrights, and on top of that, the book ends up being sold for a lot of money (which is something we're against as people from developing countries don't have access to them). Thus, after a short discussion we all agreed that going through the traditional means is no longer necessary. We're all skilled in LaTeX so we don't need the services that publishers usually provide for formatting the book. As a matter of fact, we're not planning on making any profit either, so we're very excited about the opportunity to provide the book as an open electronic document.

The main question we have is how do we make sure that  people can cite our book and that we have a way to count the citations?

Comment: What kind of book are you talking about? A textbook? If so, then why are you concerned about citations? People don't normally cite textbooks. Your remarks about publishing contracts seem overly generalized to me. The terms of a publishing contract vary between publishers and are negotiable, although you may not be able to negotiate what you want. Note that some publishers are OK with having an electronic version of the book available for free, or may be willing to negotiate such a contract.

Comment: _The main question we have is how do we make sure that people can cite our book_ — Fill it with useful content that people want to cite.

Comment: I want to add that now you have heard repeatedly that some of your impressions on traditional publishing are not true in general.

Comment: wouldn't a traditional publisher help with advertising the book and distributing it?  i third (fourth?) those who have suggested you reconsider your views on traditional publishers.

Comment: @JeffE that's obvious, but is it the DOI that's important? Or the ISBN?

Comment: @BenCrowell people do cite textbooks, at least in engineering. It doesn't happen that often but it happens.

Comment: You don't need a DOI nor ISBN to get citations. As @JeffE said: "Fill it with useful content that people want to cite." Nevertheless, perhaps distribute it via https://arxiv.org/ to ensure some form of version control (i.e., people can cite a particular version).

Comment: @user2768 that doesn't make sense. If the book has no DOI nor ISBN, how is a computer supposed to increase citation counts? I'm sure the engines don't add citations based on the indexing of the title of a book.

Comment: @aaragon, computers don't make citations, people do. Computers merely find citations made by people and list them. Computers don't solely rely on DOIs and ISBNs, because many citations don't include these details. Thus, I believe computers are using titles and other details.

Comment: Google crawl the web for .pdf files that include "the title of the paper ... in a large font on top of the first page, the authors of the paper ... below the title ..., and ... a bibliography section ... at the end." Such documents are considered for inclusion in Google Scholar. (Source: https://scholar.google.fr/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) 

Google are also parsing the bibliography to build a list of citations. As a minimum, three pieces of data are required: title, author, and publication date. (Source: https://scholar.google.fr/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing)

Comment: @user2768 that source you refer to states `This documentation describes the technology behind indexing of websites with scholarly articles in Google Scholar. It's written for webmasters who would like their papers included in Google Scholar search results.` That's not what I'm looking for. Besides, I'm also interested in Scopus and the web of science which I guess are "more conservative" than the Google scholar web crawlers.

Comment: [This](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) is an example of a book that was published by a commercial publisher (cheap, BTW), and at the same time, feely available online. That gets you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the things you have said in comments, it seems you may believe that

1. either a DOI and/or ISBN is *required* in order for services like Google Scholar, Scopus, or Web of Science to list a document and count citations for it, and
2. that your document *only* needs to have the "right" identifier for these services to "count" it.

Neither of those is true. Google Scholar, Scopus, and Web of Science each have specific inclusion criteria that determine whether it will index a document. The inclusion criteria do not care what kind of identifier (DOI or ISBN) the document has. Rather,

- Google Scholar is not selective: if a PDF document has a title, a list  of authors, and a bibliography section, it may be indexed.
- Scopus and Web of Science are selective: they only include documents that have been specifically chosen for inclusion (or, that have been published in a serial, like a journal, conference, or book series, that has been specifically selected for inclusion.)

If a document is indexed by one of these services, citations of that document in other indexed documents will be counted, even if the citations don't include a DOI or ISBN. Each of these services has an internal record identifier for every document it indexes, and counts a citation when it encounters a reference  with the same title, authors, date and other publication information (e.g. journal name and issue, or book publisher.) They do not rely on DOI or ISBN to identify a document for purposes of counting citations; many citation styles don't include DOI or ISBN.

In particular, here is more information about inclusion criteria for each of those three:

- A document will be indexed by Google Scholar if you make it available online and make it ["look" like a scholarly document following these criteria](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html), and citations of your ebook in other documents indexed by Google Scholar will be counted in Scholar's citation count even if it has no ISBN or DOI. (See e.g. all the arXiv documents that are indexed by Google Scholar, with "citation counting".)
- A document will be indexed by Scopus if it is published in one of the journals, conference proceedings, or book series [included in Scopus](https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/content/content-policy-and-selection). In particular, here are the criteria by which they select books to include:

> Book selection is via a publisher-based approach (no individual book suggestions are considered). As the selection is evaluated on a per book basis, the Content Selection and Advisory Board (CSAB) is not involved in the evaluation of this content type. A dedicated group of highly educated individuals are responsible for the publisher selection process. All books from selected publishers deemed "in scope" will be selected for coverage. Priority and selection of book list from a specific publisher depends on:
>
> 1. Reputation and impact of the publisher
> 2. Size and subject area of the books list
> 3. Availability and format of the book content
> 4. Publication policy and editorial mission
> 5. Quality of published book content

- A document will be indexed by Web of Science if it is published in [a journal that has been selected for inclusion](http://wokinfo.com/essays/journal-selection-process/), a [conference proceedings that has been selected for inclusion](http://wokinfo.com/products_tools/multidisciplinary/webofscience/cpci/cpciessay/), or if it is a [book that is selected for inclusion](http://wokinfo.com/media/pdf/BKCI-SelectionEssay_web.pdf).  Judging by their book selection criteria, it does not appear as if self-published non-peer-reviewed books will qualify:

> As with journals, a peer review process is also associated with scholarly books, and Thomson Reuters relies on the integrity of the publisher to insure that book content is valid and original.

Answer (score 6):

> I have heard repeatedly that people who go with a traditional
>   publisher don't get any royalties,

- this is true if you freely decide to sign a contract renouncing any royalties. Not otherwise.

> they transfer the copyrights,

- this is true if you freely decide to sign a contract transferring the copyright. Not otherwise.

> and on top of that, the book ends up being sold for a lot of money (which is something we're against as people from developing countries don't have access to them).

- this is true if you agree to it and if you freely decide to sign a contract giving exclusive worldwide rights to one publisher, as opposed to using different publishers in different territories.

If you choose to give a publisher print rights only, and the publisher chooses to buy the print rights only, then you are free to publish electronically. Moreover, since e-books are such a rotten medium for textbooks, quite a proportion of e-book readers will end up buying the print edition anyway.

If you don't find a publisher who is happy to do what you want, **self-publish a printed edition.** To do this:

- Get an ISBN. There are official agencies for this in most countries.
- **either** find a printer who will print you 100 copies (this is very common nowaday, and cheap: they will digitally print short runs and if it ever gets hugely popular they'll lithographically print long runs even cheaper).
- **or** go for print-on-demand, with Lulu or even Amazon. Do this if the price doesn't matter because you're mostly interested in free e-books.
- In the process of getting an ISBN you enter the full bibliographical data into a public database, so everyone will know how to cite you.

Comment: So you are saying that only the ISBN is enough to get the citation count? I guess what I don't really understand is how citations work for a book through an ISBN, because AFAIK the ISBN is just a record in a database that contains info about the book, and this has nothing to do with citations.

Comment: No, my point was that people who cite things *want something to cite*, which "e-book downloadable through a URL which will disappear next week" does not provide and "printed book listed in all the bibliographical databases" does. The ISBN is a way of ensuring this.

Comment: Do you know how citation works for books? Say I publish an article that cites a book with ISBN XXXXX, when the article is analyzed by citation databases like Scopus or the web of science, they start a counter with the ISBN? What about the DOI? I'm really curious and I want to know for sure our book will be cited.

Comment: Nearly all citation styles require ISBN for print books, and a DOI for electronic publications. Because the formats are exclusive, both are used as an effective indexing system for citation databases. Citations from the print and citations from the digital source will therefore usually be tracked seperately.

Comment: @WeckarE. you're implying that there would be two citation counts for the book. Now I'm quite confused because if we have both the ISBN and the DOI, a citation that contains both fields would thus count towards both counters, wouldn't it?

Comment: @aaragon Depending on the specific algorithms used (they vary a bit from service to service) either citations do count double, or they get added to only one of the counts. In most cases, though, this issue doesn't come up: Properly citing you would only use ISBN if you're using the print source, and only use DOI if you're using the electronic source. There is no logical place for overlap there.

Comment: @WeckarE. so then you would recommend that we associate only one identifier to each, correct? Because I believe we add the DOI to the ISBN info (but not the other way around?).

Comment: Yes. Any publication should have only at most one DOI and one ISBN. But it can have both, if it meant for both print and electronic distribution.