# Bibliographical treatment of ebooks

Tags: publications

Does Google scholar pick up references to self published ebooks?

Comment: This answer seems to cover your question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/72204/33210

Comment: Your question omits the very critical detail of "self-published"...